# Fourier transform of Feynman Integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, feynman-diagrams, integration

In Nastase, [Introduction to AdS/CFT](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0689), the first chapter talks a little about the star-triangle duality. In fact, it was claimed that the Fourier Transform of a Feynman-like diagram in position space in the form of a Triangle, is the Feynman diagram in momentum space, which seems like a star.

What i mean is: The Fourier transform of

[image]

to momentum space reduces to

[image]

I have tried to evaluate it, but i was not able to do the last integral. First we start with

$$ \int d^4 x_1 d^4 x_2 d^4 x_3 \left ( d^4 p d^4 q d^4 v \frac{1}{p^2 q^2 v^2} e^{-ip(x_1-x_2)-iq(x_2-x_3)-iv(x_3-x_1)} \right ) e^{-i(q_1 x_1 + q_2 x_2 + q_3 x_3)}$$

Doing all the $\delta$ integrations, i end with a term like

$$ \int  d^4v \frac{1}{(q_1+v)^2} \frac{1}{(q_2 + q_1 + v)^2} \frac{1}{v^2} \delta(q_1+q_2+q_3) $$

While it seems right, i don't know how to evalaute the last integral. I have tried to use techniques like Feynman reparametrizations, but it didn't work (we use the Feynman parametrization for $1/(ABC)$, but we wen with an integral of $\tan^{-1}(f(1-x))$ which is a little hard to compute.

As @Physiker suggested, i have tried partial fraction as well. The problem i encounter when i do this is the ultraviolet divergente. I will split fractions in terms like $d^4 k/k^2, d^4 k/k$.

Splitting it, we can see that terms like $\int d^4 v 1/v$, when added, will vanish. Now, we end with

$$ \int d^4 v \left ( \frac{1}{q_1^2 q_3^2 v^2} + \frac{1}{q_1^2(q_1+q_3)^2 (v-q_1)^2} + \frac{1}{q_3^2(q_1 + q_3)^2 (v-q_3)^2} \right )$$

Which is equal to (since we can just translate the variable $v-a \rightarrow v$

$$ \int d^4 v \left ( \frac{1}{q_1^2 q_3^2 } + \frac{1}{q_1^2(q_1+q_3)^2 } + \frac{1}{q_3^2(q_1 + q_3)^2} \right ) \frac{1}{v^2}$$

Using $q_1+q_2+q_3=0#,

$$ \int d^4 v \left ( \frac{1}{q_1^2 q_3^2 } + \frac{1}{q_1^2 q_2^2 } + \frac{1}{q_3^2 q_2^2} \right ) \frac{1}{v^2}$$

The problem is that $\left ( \frac{1}{q_1^2 q_3^2 } + \frac{1}{q_1^2 q_2^2 } + \frac{1}{q_3^2 q_2^2} \right ) $ does not reduce exactly to $1/(q_1^2 q_2^2 q_3^2)$, as it should.

Comment: Partial fractions?

Comment: You need to show your work. Why didn't Feynman-Schwinger parameterization work?

Comment: @Physiker I tried to show it.

Comment: @Prahar We end with a hard integral, which i doubtly it is the correctly way to do it